# Error parametro escritura

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Quiero generar un dialogo cada vez que aparece un personaje pero cuando le paso el parametro solo me genera la letra L ya que no se como general un bucle animado al mostrar el texto.

```js
var i = 0;
var speed = 50;

let typeWriter =((txt)=> {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
});
typeWriter('Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.');
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Solo te falta enviar el parámetro: `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, txt);`

Comment: Plaf, gracias T.T